# react define component as const

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to declare/render a builtin class on platform basis.

Is that works?
outside the render function

```
const KeyboardAvoidingView_C = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? KeyboardAvoidingView : View;
```

and using like;

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView_C>
...
</KeyboardAvoidingView_C>
```

Comment: You can write it another way. 
{Platform.OS == 'ios' ? <KeyboardAvoidingView  /> : <View /> } This is a cleaner approach in react, official documentation they also suggest this approach.

Comment: @ramibad560 Yes It would work in that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions to make components

```
const KeyboardAvoidingView_C = (paramters) => {
  // Your code
}
```